# Is it possible to see a list of tags I have not favorited or ignored?

Tags: discussion, tagging, ignored-tags, tag-watching

For any tag, you can ignore it (questions with this tag are hidden or grayed out), favorite it (questions with this tag are highlighted), or neither. By going to Preferences on the Edit Profile & Settings tab of your profile, you can see a list of tags you have favorited and a list of tags you have ignored. Is it possible to find a list of the other tags?

Comment: Just in case: there are more than 1600 tags (counting synonyms separately), and approximately 1400 unique ones. Here is [a list of all tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags). (I have to admit I'm not sure what such a list would be for).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I would like to block some more tags (I've blocked many already). I was hoping there was a list of tags that I haven't blocked which I could check. I'd rather not go through 41 pages of tags, some of which I have already blocked.

Comment: My advice in that case is to occasionally go through the front page and notice tags used there that you would like to hide. That way you only hide tags actually in use, rather than spending time on finding and hiding a tag nobody ever uses.

Comment: I am not sure to which extent this is helpful, but they are shown if you start editing favorite tags, at least according to this post on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217792/cant-see-my-ignored-tags-anymore-unless-editing-favorite-tags

Comment: @MartinSleziak: That seems to be referring to ignored tags. I can already see a list of them in my profile.

Comment: You are right. I was not reading careful enough. Sorry.